# ¿Una Sentencia es lo mismo que una Linea de Código?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

Investigué en varias páginas de Internet sobre cuál es la definición de "sentencia" en lenguajes de programación y en la mayoría explicaba simplemente que es una línea de código, pero si comparamos esta definición con la PROGRAMACIÓN OFUSCADA, veremos que se puede utilizar una misma sentencia en varias líneas de código o muchas sentencias en una misma línea de código , por lo que seria una mala explicación.

Entonces estaría bien definir a la sentencia como una instrucción o todo aquello que finalice con un punto y coma.

Comment: Coincido con que para escribir una sentencia se pueden usar varias líneas de código, y con que una misma sentencia puede estar repetida en varias líneas de  código. Haciendo una analogía con un libro, diría que una sentencia es una frase, ya que puede ocupar más de una línea en el libro y puede aparecer varias veces en el libro. Así pues, sí me gusta lo que dices de que una sentencia es una instrucción, y que se termina donde se encuentra el ";" .

Answer (score 9):

Una sentencia es el elemento básico de un lenguaje de programación, partiendo de esta base y teniendo en cuenta de que en varios lenguajes una sentencia termina con el `;`...

La diferencia que puede tener a una línea de código es que una sentencia puede llevar varias líneas de código dependiendo de las convenciones del lenguaje y otros factores.

## Sentencia

```
itemView.Question
   .AnswersJSON(itemView.Answer.ToJSONString())
   .Modified(DateTime.Now)
   .ModifiedBy(User.Identity.Name);
```

## Líneas de código

```
var a = 1; 
Function (a, b);
```

Como puedes ver en la **sentencia** que te adjunto se ven **varias líneas de código** que dan valores a varias propiedades de un objeto, mientras que las **líneas de código** se pueden interpretar como **sentencias**, siendo estas de una sola línea.

En este caso el código está en `C#` pero creo que para explicar la diferencia entre una sentencia o una línea de código es igual de válido.

Te dejo también [este enlace](http://teleformacion.edu.aytolacoruna.es/PASCAL/document/senten.htm) en el que se comentan distintas definiciones sobre las sentencias y expresiones.

Comment: No por nada se llaman _"Lenguajes de Programación"_. :)